# Swift 3: PerformSegue WithIdentifier Not Displaying View Controller, No Errors

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3

When I execute the line below, my destination view controller is not visually presented but there are no errors in the log:

```
performSegue (withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController", sender: self)
```

Let's step back from a problem. Imagine my successful setup: `ViewController` is loaded and upon some user action the above line would actually open a new `DetailsViewController`. I tested - everything works as expected - so I know it works.

But the problem presenting `DetailsViewController` begins when I decide to implement some third party framework by adding a `CamViewController` to my `ViewController` and perform segue upon element tap inside `CamViewController`, then delegate method passing this action back to `ViewController` from which I would open `DetailsViewController`. With this architecture setup I get no errors in a log but visually nothing is opening. No `DetailsViewController` ever presented.

A bit more details of architecture:

- `ViewController` presents `CamViewController` with line `self.present(camViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
- `CamViewController` implements a protocol to call some method on user action
- `ViewController` conforms to `CamViewController` protocol and delegate method successfully runs on user action (log shows it is working)
- Calling `DetailsViewController` with segue identifier is executed successfully `performSegue (withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController", sender: self)` but `DetailsViewController` is never displayed on screen.
- This method below prints `prepare for segue Optional("DetailsViewController")` which sounds correct.

  ```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     print("prepare for segue \(segue.identifier)")
  }
  ```

I also tried adding `super.performSegue` - no luck

Comment: Can you give me the details about the camviewcontroller you are adding to the view controller

Comment: Sure, it is `open class CamViewController: UIViewController, XYManagerDelegate`

Comment: your log says nothing ? maybe something about view hierarchy

Comment: How do you dismiss CamViewController?  Is it possible that you have two instances of DetailsViewController after CamViewController was shown?

Answer (score 0):

First I would change your segue code to something more like this.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "DetailsViewController"){
        print("prepare for segue DetailsViewController")
    }  else {
        print("prepare for segue other")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It prints `prepare for segue DetailsViewController` as expected so I know the segue is valid and seems to be triggered correctly. But no view controller displayed.